# What is the full list of "usable" Minecraft items capable of right-click detection using Brigadier?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Before Brigadier (the command system that 1.13+ uses) was introduced, you could detect a right-click with anything that had the `stat.useItem` criteria. However, since scoreboard criteria (among many other things) were changed with the 1.13 update, `stat.useItem` was changed to `minecraft.used`, and gives the entire item selection rather than just a few.

[The Wiki section on scoreboard criteria](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria) doesn't list criteria types with `minecraft` as the start of their IDs at all, which means the following criteria are all left out: `minecraft.broken`, `minecraft.crafted`, `minecraft.custom`, `minecraft.dropped`, `minecraft.killed`, `minecraft.killed_by`, `minecraft.mined`, `minecraft.picked_up`, and last but not least `minecraft.used`.

Due to all of these being left out, there's no publicly available list of all the possible "usable" items to allow for simple right-click detection (think the usability of the original right-click detection, the Carrot on a Stick).

What's the full list of actual "usable" items and/or tools that is trackable via the `minecraft.used` criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few items that can be detected by right-clicking in the air. The `carrot_on_a_stick` and `warped_fungus_on_a_stick` both work. and then all trowable items such as:

- ender pearl
- eye of ender
- lingering potions
- Bottle o' Enchanting
- splash potions
- snowballs
- Bow and Crossbow if you fire an arrow
- etc.

But only the two "on a stick" items can be detected without doing anything.

All other blocks will be detected when you place them, other items will be detected when you use them for a task, for example uses an axe to strip a log.

During my testing, I also found a few items what is impossible to test for such as:

- air
- arrow
- any kind of dye (even if you dye something like a sheep it doesn't detect it)
- bone
- shield
- all armor
- elytra
- book
- and probably some more